# Show a block if the page content has a specific taxonomy term

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, routes, blocks

I've got a content type (**Brands**) and a taxonomy vocab (**Product Type**) with a few options, so you can "tag" a brand with a specific product type. Using Views I'm filtering my content on my pages depending on the taxonomy term.

I've got a Views block (I'm also using this block as a dropdown in my navigation with the Menu Views module) that lists all the brands tagged with a specific taxonomy term. What I want now is that this block also shows up in my right sidebar on all the pages that display content of 'Brands' and are tagged with a specific term from my taxonomy vocab.

Example (menu structure):

```
* Product Type A
  - Brand 1 
  - Brand 2
  - Brand 3
* Product Type B
  - Brand 2
  - Brand 4
  - Brand 5
```

If I'm on the 'Brand 1'-page, the 'Brands' list under **Product Type A** should show up in my right sidebar.

I can't filter using the 'normal' way since its the same content type, and the same taxonony vocab. And by the 'normal' way I mean using a URL pattern for the content type and then use 
`contenttype/*` on my block config page.

Sidenote: I'm also adding a class to my `<body>` using `hook_preprocess_html()` for all the brand pages. So all the brands tagged with **Product Type A** have a class of `product-type-a` on their `<body>` field. Is there a way so show/hide blocks depending on a class through code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add two contextual filters to your view block:

**Important:** Use `this block (override)` for all these settings.

```
Content: Nid
```

Provide default value: Content ID from URL

More:check: exclude.

*This contextual filter will exclude `Brand X` from the list if you're visiting `Brand X` page.*

```
Content: Has taxonomy term ID
```

Provide default value: Taxonomy term ID from URL

check:  Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks.

When the filter value IS available or a default is provided:

Override title: Type here your `block title` using `%1` for the first argument, `%2` for the second, etc.

*This contextual filter will list all your brands from current visited Product type*

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help.